# Why this coding does not load admin dashboard? problem with middleware or auth? Laravel 8

Tags: authentication

```
Why this coding does not load admin dashboard? problem with middleware or auth? Laravel 8
```

This is the coding. All the files I modified in this regards are as follows. Please help me

This is the AdminController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
//use session;




class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function dashboard(){
        return view('admin.admin_dashboard');
    }

    public function login(Request $request){
        if($request->isMethod('post')){
           $data =$request->all();
         //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;
         
          if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email'=>$data['email'],'password'=>$data['password']])){
            return redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }else{ session::flash('error_message','Invalid email or password');
            redirect()->back();      
                 }
              }
        return view('admin.admin_login');
    }
   
    
    
}
```

This is the Admin model. It is checked No error in the model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;
    protected $guard='admin';
    protected $fillable=[
        'name','email','password',
    ];
    protected $hidden=[
        'password','rememberToken',
    ];
}
```

This is the Middleware file. I think the error may be in this area. Because it works outside the middleware for 2nd auth.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Auth;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Admin
{
    
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
         if(!Auth::guard('admin')->check()){
           return redirect('/admin');
            
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Finally this is admin dashboard rout is not executing